# SQL Query to combine results and show in a PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below mentioned are the two of my queries:

```
SELECT  WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN, COUNT(DPS_NUMBER) as TotalDPS
FROM DispatcherProductivity
WHERE DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp>='12/04/2014 10:30 AM' 
AND DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp<='12/05/2014 10:30 AM'
GROUP BY WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN
ORDER BY TotalDPS

SELECT  STATUS, COUNT(DPS_NUMBER) AS TotalDPS
FROM DispatcherProductivity
WHERE DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp>='12/04/2014 10:30 AM' 
AND DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp<='12/05/2014 10:30 AM'
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY TotalDPS
```

Their respective Results are:

```
WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN    TotalDPS
A_S 72
T_I_S   133

STATUS  TotalDPS
ID  1
Can 2
NHD 3
SED 14
Ord 185
```

I would like to get the results in this format:

```
WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN ID Can NHD SED Ord
A_S                         2   70
T_I_S            1  2   3   12  115
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use conditional aggregations for pivots.  In this case:

```
SELECT WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN, COUNT(DPS_NUMBER) as TotalDPS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ID' THEN DPS_Number END) as ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Can' THEN DPS_Number END) as Can,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'NHD' THEN DPS_Number END) as NHD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SED' THEN DPS_Number END) as SED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Ord' THEN DPS_Number END) as Ord
FROM DispatcherProductivity
WHERE DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp >= '12/04/2014 10:30 AM' AND
      DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp <= '12/05/2014 10:30 AM'
GROUP BY WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN;
```

I would also recommend that you use YYYY-MM-DD format for your dates.  I, for one, don't know if your dates are for December or April and May.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function for this:

```
SELECT  pvt.WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN,
        pvt.[ID],
        pvt.[Can],
        pvt.[NHD],
        pvt.[SED],
        pvt.[Ord]
FROM    (   SELECT  WINDOWS_NT_LOGIN, STATUS, DPS_NUMBER
            FROM    DispatcherProductivity
            WHERE   DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp>='20141204 10:30:00' 
            AND     DPS_Processed_Time_Stamp<='20141205 10:30:00'
        ) AS t
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(DPS_NUMBER)
            FOR STATUS IN ([ID], [Can], [NHD], [SED], [Ord])
        ) AS pvt;
```

*N.B. I changed your dates to the culture invariant format `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss`, however, I was not sure if `12/04/2014` was supposed to tbe 12th April, or 4th December (the exact problem with that format), so it is possible I have put the wrong dates in. I assumed you meant 4th December as that is today.*

*For further reading read [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)*